# Import / Export CSV or Excel file in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle I have to load Excel/Csv file data to Oracle Table. My file contains around 50 columns. The size of the file is nearly 20 MB. I am trying to find the best way to load my file data to Table. I tried with SQL Loader but it through the following error.

SQL*Loader-700: Out of memory while performing essential allocations [7]

Please suggest me any best way to do this process.

Note: I am unable to open the file due to its size even it has been exported from other source.

Comment: 20MB, not GB? That's not a large file; any text editor (aside from Windows 9X's notepad) should be able to open that.

Comment: My text editor is hanging when I try to open it so I am not able to find the number of records in it.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me the best way to load the data to Table.

Comment: 1. Use another text editor, or migrate away from your Pentium 1 processor. 2. Use that text editor and a few find/replaces to build valid SQL out of your CSV.

Comment: Data file contains more than 5 million records

Comment: Unless each of your record is less than 4 bytes long only, your 20MB size is wrong then.